# Как дождаться окончания загрузки страницы в WebView2?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, webview

Жду пока на страницу загрузится нужный элемент ( через webview2 ), после чего хочу нажать на него через Send.Keys. Не знал как дождаться и придумал это:

```
private async void CheckLoading()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        do
        {
            list.Clear();
            var context = await webView23.CoreWebView2.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();     // Получает что-то вроде Document 
            var sector = await context.QuerySelectorAllAsync<HtmlDivElement>("div");     // Собирает все <DIV>

            foreach (var text in sector)
            {
                var divtext = await text.GetInnerTextAsync();                            // Текст из загруженных <DIV>
                list.Add(divtext);                                                       // Добавляет в list
            }
        } while (list[2].ToString() != "Product Activation");                            // Если в листе есть нужный текст, то нужный <DIV> загружен, могу с ним работать
       
         MessageBox.Show("Найдено");
    }

    private void buttonSend_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckLoading();
    }
```

Никогда не получаю сообщение "Совпадение", если нажму Click_button_1 на кнопку до появления нужного элемента. ( **а в этом и смысл** ).
Хотя вроде до этого момента, работа должна происходить в цикле.

Я понимаю что это связано как-то с Async методом, но не более. Помогите мне решить эту задачу.

Comment: Хочу добавить, что событие NavigationComplite из WebViev2 срабатывает моментально, но JSON продолжают загружаться постепенно формируя новые HTML элементы внутри документа. Нужный мне подгружается в самом конце.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы дождаться окончания загрузки страницы, создайте обработчик

```
private void OnCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Страница загружена");
}
```

И подпишитесь на событие, один раз

```
WebView.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted += OnCompleted;
```

Когда не надо будет вызывать обработчик, отпишитесь обратно

```
WebView.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted -= OnCompleted;
```

---

`async void` нужно использовать с осторожностью. Следует блокировать повторное нажатие кнопки, иначе будет каша. Ну и добавить `try-catch` для обработки исключений.

Кстати, можно дождаться освобождения браузера асинхронно, пробросив событие `NavigationCompleted` через `TaskCompletionSource`.

Пример:

```
public async Task NavigateAsync(string url)
{
    TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();
    EventHandler<CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs> handler = async (s, e) => tcs.SetResult();
    try
    {
        webView.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted += handler;
        webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(url);
        await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        webView.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted -= handler;
    }
}

private async void buttonSend_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        await NavigateAsync("https://ru.stackoverflow.com");
        await WaitForElementAsync();
        MessageBox.Show("Страница загружена");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    btn.Enabled = true;
}

private async Task WaitForElementAsync()
{
    var context = await webView23.CoreWebView2.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();
    while (true)
    {
        var nodes = await context.QuerySelectorAllAsync<HtmlDivElement>("div");
        var text = await nodes.Skip(2).First().GetInnerTextAsync();
        if (text != "Product Activation")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Найдено");
            break;
        }
        await Task.Delay(50);
    }
}
```

Смысл здесь в том, что пока страница не будет загружена, нет никакого смысл начинать парсить HTML.

Так же подозреваю, что `context` не следует создавать кучу раз в цикле. Вынесите его создание из цикла. Если нужно провести какое-то сложное ожидание, например отследить появление элемента на странице по каким-то непредсказуемым условиям, то решать такой вопрос следует средствами JavaScript, а не поллингом. В JS есть класс `MutationObserver`, его можно повесить на ноду в DOM и он вызовет функцию, когда DOM изменится, с этой функции можно вызвать колбэк, который пробросить в C# через тот же JS Promise. Да, в JavaScript тоже есть асиинхронность. Опрашивать DOM 100500 раз в секунду полностью повесив UI поток этими проверками - так себе идея.

Comment: Дело в том, что событие webView23_NavigationCompleted срабатывает моментально, а вот нужный Json подгружается еще секунд 5 . Кнопка нажмется до появления контрола на который она должна нажать.

https://microsoft.gointeract.io/interact/index?interaction=1461173234028-3884f8602eccbe259104553afa8415434b4581-05d1&accountId=microsoft&loadFrom=CDN&appkey=196de13c-e946-4531-98f6-2719ec8405ce&Language=English&name=pana&CountryCode=en-US&Click%20To%20Call%20Caller%20Id=+16265860337&startedFromSmsToken=e9dmQhQ&dnis=1&token=UEuUbt Просто подставьте эту ссылку в свой код. Суть проблемы именно в этом

Comment: @ПавелВайт ну и в чем проблема, вешайте MutaionObserver на нужное место и следите за изменениями на странице. Как JS скрипты выполнять, вы же знаете?

Comment: @ПавелВайт окей, дописал метод по поиску элемента на базе вашего способа с поллингом раз в 50мс.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваши ответы, и что откликнулись. Пойду почитаю что такое MutaionObserver. Ну я выполнял так, как-раз что бы нажать на кнопку которую жду `var btnCls = $"document.getElementById('{btnId}').click()";` и  `var k = webView23.ExecuteScriptAsync(btnCls);`

Comment: @ПавелВайт ошибку нашел. Чтобы было как у вас надо не `Skip(1)` а `Skip(2)`, исправил, еще `.GetInnerTextAsync()` на место вставил